# Is it possible to pull the transactions that the Moonbeam collators are sending to the Polkadot relay chain?

Tags: polkadot-js, polkadot, collator, moonbeam

Currently, working inside the Moonbeam interface and was wondering if it was possible to pull the group of transactions that the Moonbeam collators are sending to the Polkadot Relay Chain before the validators finalize them?

I got the notion that this would be possible from the line in Coinbase's overview of the Moonbeam Consensus system:
"Collators on Moonbeam and Moonriver collect transactions from the network and submit them to the Relay Chain’s validators to be finalized, and help to secure the chain."

I am specifically referencing the collection of transactions that the Collators on both Moonbeam and Moonriver have sent to the Polkadot and Co. relay chains. Is this possible to accomplish through the py-substrate-interface or the polkadot.js interface? Or any correction on my thought process would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking about the blocks that the moonbeam collators send to Polkadot, or the transaction pool of moonbeam itself?

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi I am asking about the blocks that the moonbeam collators send to Polkadot.

Comment: Just have a look at the finalized blocks of the Moonbeam chain. These are what the collators have sent to relay-chain validators. There are maybe competing blocks that have been lost in cyberspace, and there is no good archive for such blocks at this time.